# Ms Sql Convert and insert between 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, varchar, bigint

I have two databases.I insert data from **DATABASE_2** TO **DATABASE_1** however i need to convert some column.

I must convert **Customer_Telephone_Number** from **varchar** to **bigint** after that insert it.

So,

My Question is in below.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DATABASE_1.dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE ON

INSERT INTO DATABASE_1.dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE 
(
Customer_Id,
Customer_Telephone_Number
)
Select

Customer_Id,
Customer_Telephone_Number // This is varchar so i need to convert it to Big int.

from 
DATABASE_2.DBO.CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data stored is without spaces or other non numeric symbols:

```
Select
    Customer_Id,
    CONVERT(BIGINT,Customer_Telephone_Number)    
from 
    DATABASE_2.DBO.CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

For instance, if there is value with `(222)-3333-333` it would fail. If the value was `2223333333` it would succeed

Comment: Malakas i will open one more question about ( and ) .Maybe you can help me.Thanks.

Comment: just joking.Anyway.I will open one more question about "(" and ")" if you help me i will be happy.Thanks

Comment: No problem. Just wondering. I will keep an eye for your next one.